# Ввод строки с помощью getch()

Tags: c, память, ввод

Здравствуйте, мне необходимо сделать функцию ввода строки, строка вводится до тех пор, пока пользователь не нажмет ENTER.
Вот собственно сам код:

```
char* GetLine() {
    char* line = NULL;
    char ch;
    int i = 0;
    while(true){
        ch = getch(); //Считываем, но не выводим символ
        switch(ch) {
            case '\r':
                line = (char*)realloc(line, (i + 1) * sizeof(char));
                line[i++] = '\0'; //Признак конца строки
                return line;
            case '\b':
                printf("\b \b"); //Удаляем символ в консоле
                if (i > 0) i--;
                break;
            default:
                putchar(ch);
                line = (char*)realloc(line, (i + 1) * sizeof(char));
                line[i++] = ch;
        }
    }
}
```

В чем собственно проблема, мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии отдельных клавиш (F1-F12, Esc, цифры на numpade и т.п) они не выводились в консоль. Я знаю, что можно свитчем сделать перебор всех клавиш сканкодом, но мне кажется должно быть решение полегче.

Comment: Если `getch` возвращает 0 - игнорируйте следующий возврат. С выделением памяти у вас подход неверный - на каждый символ выделять. Выделяйте куском, при необходимости - удваивайте, будет куда эффективнее. И последнее - задача так и стоит - именно `getch()`? Не просто считывать, динамически увеличивая размер буфера, а именно этой функцией? потому что все то же делается куда проще через `getchar` например, и без этих извращений...

Comment: Я делал ввод с getchar() (всё работало норм) , но препод в тупик поставил, мол , я в функции getchar() ввожу не один символ, а целую строку (про некий буфер ввода не знал ещё). А как сам буфер собственно увеличить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В комментарии ответить - места не хватит...

В данном случае вас совершенно не должен волновать буфер ввода, так как вы все равно заканчиваете свой ввод нажатием Enter. Как его отрабатывает компилятор и операционная система - это их проблемы. Вот код -

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * read()
{
    size_t size = 8;
    char * buf = (char*)malloc(size*sizeof(char));
    size_t count = 0;

    for(int c = ' ' /*Неважно что, лишь бы не нуль */;c;)
    {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF || c == '\n')
            c = '\0';
        if (count == size)
        {
            buf = (char*)realloc(buf,size *= 2);
        }
        buf[count++] = c;
    }
    return buf;
}


int main()
{
    char * s = read();
    printf("You wrote: [%s]\n",s);
    free(s);
}
```

Вводите хоть мегабайтную строку, лишь бы `realloc` отработал. Препод тут, я считаю, в корне неправ.

В случае `getch()` всякие функциональные клавиши дают 2 кода подряд, первый - 0 или 0xE0. Если видите такой код - считывайте второй код и игнорируйте их оба. Только вот о, скажем, русском языке при этом придется забыть...